# Is there a solution to change the post-submission behavior of a sign up form without backend support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, backend

- The form action link is redirecting users to a 'Thank You' page but I want to show the thank you message on the email sign up modal itself after submitting. I have no support to know the details about the back-end language.
- Since the submission page is a different domain we are getting CORS error so we need API document for that.

  - I am working on this site. https://www.steamboat.com/email/email-signup
  - Currently, they are landing the users on a thank you after submitting the form, I am creating a modal and want the users to see the thank message on the modal itself.

Comment: This depends hugely on what you are able to do and how the backend processes the form. But if you can write your own jQuery code, you could easily just send the form using AJAX and capture the response, then show that in the modal. No need to change the action link. In fact, changing the action link would probably break the form.

Comment: Please show some example of what you're trying to do, and clarify what language you're working in, etc

Comment: @TatuUlmanen is it possible for you to explain your solution in detail?

Comment: @jhaagsma you can check https://www.steamboat.com/email/email-signup. But I am displaying an email sign up modal and I have absolutely no back-end support to make sure the users cannot be redirected to the existing thank you page. I can work on jQuery, do you have a solution in some other language?

Comment: @TatuUlmanen Since the submission page is a different domain we are getting CORS error so we need API document for that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `action="javascript:void(0)"` and then handle your form data submission with Ajax instead of redirecting to a Thank you page.

For example:

```js
$("form").submit( 

  function(){
      //Send data with Ajax to the backend using $.ajax() function and then on the callBack function do something with your html e.g.

  $("form").fadeOut(function() {    
       $(".response").fadeIn();
  });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form action="javascript:void(0)">
  <input type="text" name="userName">
  <input type="text" name="password">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<div class="response" style="display:none">
  Thank you!!
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since the submission page is a different domain we are getting CORS error so we need api document for that

Comment: Hmm ok, I just edited the answer with an example of handling the front-end... the CORS problem is most likely to be related to the back-end configuration... Can you give more explanation about your back-end, e.g. language or framework that you are using?

Comment: I have no support to get any information about the back-end. All I have is the website https://www.steamboat.com/email/email-signup for which I need to run an A/B test, I need to create a modal without landing the users of thank you page.

Comment: First I have to understand your problem then... How are you generating this form? It seems to be generated by an external system giving its configuration, is it correct?! Or have you actually coded this form?

Comment: This is the link of the modal I am working on https://www.steamboat.com/?at_preview_token=oaK0ITDu5Hm4f8dYMW6q39I4r7c1tJUDyoob0HiAFR0%3D&at_preview_index=1_2&at_preview_listed_activities_only=true 
Scroll till 1000px and you will get the modal on your screen

Comment: Yes, got it... but my question is: do you actually have access to this form html code? can you change the action from 

action=https://www.pages08.net/alterramountaincompany/steamboat/SB_WebsiteEmailSignups?sessionGUID=ed72ee64-6a00-b19a-d3c8-2eba4dd09899&trackedExternalFormPost=1&webSyncID=15c1b23d-61ca-9e32-b0ca-0e74058cc35d&sessionGUID=8aba57cc-3c5d-de3c-9a4c-e68e737a1394&trackedExternalFormPost=1

to 

action="javascript:void(0)" ?

Or is it generated from an external system?

Comment: It is generated from an external system.But I am implementing this test on Adobe Target so I am sure I can overwrite the code

Comment: Ok, so just overwrite the code, if you can overwrite the code and use jQuery, my answer suits you doesn't it? Check the codepen sample code that I put on the answer...

Comment: Most likely! I am trying to implement your solution, I will keep you posted. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Perfect, keep me updated, and if you can please upvote my solution if it solves your problem I would be glad, cause someone just downvoted it for no apparent reason...

Comment: Yes, I did upvote your answer. I am new to this platform and its the first time I am posting a question and I already have -4 on it.